# Not able to debug my app on android device

Tags: java, android

I'm not able to debug my app on my android device after I changed the package name (it was working before). I keep seeing the message below in Debug tab when I click the "Run" button.

This is the error message:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.anhnt/com.focuslab.flashlightnotif.activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.anhnt/com.focuslab.flashlightnotif.activities.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.anhnt/com.focuslab.flashlightnotif.activities.MainActivity} does not exist.
Error while Launching activity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the package name also in the Manifest File and in the Gradle File

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in the Manifest you have updated the information. The manifest file is currently searching to launch *MainActivity* in `com.anhnt/com.focuslab.flashlightnotif.activities` and I believe you have refactored the path to reach it.

Comment: Hi Cedric, thanks for your answer.

I followed your instructions, but unfortunately the problem still persists.